# How to prompt user that asks a user for a file name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going through Intro to Programming so basic stuff here, I have an assignment to "write a program that asks a user for a file name and then displays the first 5 lines of the file," I just can't figure out how to use the input command in this situation and then transfer to open()

Edit: Sorry here is a code snippet I had, I just don't get how to apply input from here.

```
def main():
    #This function writes to the testFile.docx file
    outfile = open('testFile.docx', 'w')
    outfile.write('Hello World\n')
    outfile.write('It is raining outside\n')
    outfile.write('Ashley is sick\n')
    outfile.write('My dogs name is Bailey\n')
    outfile.write('My cats name is Remi\n')
    outfile.write('Spam Eggs and Spam\n')
    outfile.close()

    infile = open('testFile.docx', 'r')
    testFileContent = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    print(testFileContent)
```

main()

Comment: Please post a code snippet that you've tried so that we can help.

Comment: Added in my edit above

Comment: Yeah, Please check my answer and explanation. Hope it helps!

Comment: Side-note: `.docx` indicates a Microsoft Word document. You're writing plain text, which should have a `.txt` extension if you don't want to deceive users (and trigger invalid file type associations).

Answer (score 0):

First, we ask for a filename. Then we use the `try` clause, which checks whether the file exists. If it does it will print 5 lines. If it does not, it will print `No such a file found!`

```
x = input('Enter a file name')
try:
    with open(x) as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    for i in range(5):
        print(data[i])
except:
    print('No such a file found!')
```

Comment: Unusual because where I am at in the course we have not even learned 'try' clauses yet

Comment: @JordanSweeney the `try` clause is just used when the user input invalid name. if you suppose that the file will always exist use `x = input('Enter a file name') with open(x) as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    for i in range(5):
        print(data[i])`

Answer (score 0):

`input()` is used to receive input from the user. Once we recieve the input, we use the `open()` method to read the file in **read** mode.

```
def main():
    file = input("Please enter a file name")
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    print(lines[:5])
```

The `with` statement makes sure that it closes the file automatically without explicitly calling `f.close()`

The method `f.readlines()` returns an array containing the lines in the file.

The `print()` statement prints the first 5 lines of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple function,

```
def hello_user():
    user_input = input('Enter file name: ')
    try:
        with open(user_input, 'r') as f:
            data = f.readlines()
    
        data = data[:5]
        for o in data:
            print(o.strip())

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Not found ')
```

hello_user()

1. It asks for a file name
2. If the file exists in the same directory the script is running, it opens the file and read each lines (white lines inclusive)
3. We select only the first 5 lines
4. We iterate through the list and remove the extra whitespace character(e.g \n).
5. If the file was not found,  we catch the exception.